# The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: azure, azure-queues

I'm trying to make a C# console app that adds messages to a queue. I'm following the examples about Azure Service Bus given here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-queues/

My program does nothing at the moment:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

namespace testConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I add the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll reference (as explained in the above link, 1-add dll reference and 2-add using statements) I'm getting an error upon compiling: "*The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*"

I even looked into the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll with reflector tool and it does contain Microsoft.ServiceBus namespace. Version number of the dll is 1.6.0.0 and runtime version v4.0.30319.

Any help appreciated.

-pom-

Comment: Ha! I just found the answer myself. In the console project's settings, the target framework needs to point to ".NET Framework 4" in stead of ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile". No reference errors anymore... Merry Christmas time everyone!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A common issue when using Storage and AppFabric services with a non-web applications is that the default Target Framework for Windows Forms app and Console App is .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile. Change your project's Target Framework to ".NET Framework 4.0" (full) and it will work.

Comment: I think we found thew answer at the same time... =) Thanks anyhow! I'll accept this answer (after 8 min restriction is passed)

Comment: I am astonished, that this has been issue since 2011 and hasn't been fixed my MSFT yet. But as we see, there is no "Client Profile" for .NET Framework 4.5 and 4.5.1 :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I've was that there are two packages Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus and Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus. and I was using the wrong one, so maybe was that.

In the link the package used it's Azure not Microsoft as you are importing in your project.

It's this one
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;