# Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll issue with .Net full profile configuration

Tags: c#, .net, dll, azureservicebus

I have recently run nuget auto package restore on my entire Visual Studio 2015 solution. Of course, this was a very bad idea and I spent few days fixing missing dlls and manually troubleshooting  package issues cross my 7 projects in the solution.

I, however, still face these issues:

> The type or namespace name 'Notifications' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

and

> The name 'NotificationHubClient' does not exist in the current context

That occur in this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Notifications;

namespace B8AK.Service
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for PushNotification
    /// </summary>
    public class PushNotification
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Send push notification
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="msg">Message</param>
        /// <param name="key">SPID or Customer mobile</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool Send(string msg, string key)
        {
            try
            {
                var notificationHubClint = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusPushNotificationConnectionString"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusPushNotificationName"]);
                Dictionary<string, string> param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                param.Add("message", msg);
                param.Add("alert", msg);
                var template = new TemplateNotification(param);
                List<string> tagList = new List<string>();
                tagList.Add(key);
                notificationHubClint.SendNotificationAsync(template, tagList);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Despite having the 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll' referenced in my project.

After Stackoverflowing this issue, I came cross a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561842/the-type-or-namespace-name-servicebus-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microso) that suggest to change the target framework from .Net client profile to the Full profile from the project properties, but in my case, I am already running the full .net profile.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed !

Installing this nuget package solved the problem for me:

=> Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs